# multiplication between two power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know from doing computer science that in order to calculate a power set we can use it's recursive definition (pow(S) means power set of S for the ease of notation):
let S = {a,b,c,d...} $$pow(S) = pow(\{S\setminus a\}) \cup \{ \{a\} \cup \alpha: \alpha \in pow(\{S\setminus a\})\}$$
or in other words,

> union of subsets that contains a and those who does not (reasoning/justification)

However I know that this is probably also true:
$$ U \subset S, V = S\setminus U$$
$$ pow(S) = pow(U) \times pow(V)$$

here,"$\times$" is behaves like cross product...I don't have a name for it...$$A \times B = \{a \cup b : a \in A, b \in B\}$$ when $U$ is $\{a\}$, we have: $$ \{\emptyset \cup b: b \in pow(\{S\setminus a\})\} \cup \{\{a\} \cup b: b \in pow(\{S\setminus a\})\}$$ plus, the size calculation matches:
$$2^S = 2^U \times 2^V$$

However I can not find a proof or a justification as good as the **above**... to convince myself this is true, this is killing me...

Comment: What do you mean by the "cross product"?

Comment: (Cartesian Product) every element in A concatenate with every element in B: $$\{\{1\},\{2\}\} \times \{\{3\},\{4\}\}  = \{\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\}\}$$

Comment: That's not the usual meaning of that symbol . . .

Comment: That is not the definition of Cartesian Product, which is a collection of ordered pair, not unordered sets. (And is not compatible with your usage of it in the original equation about $a$.)

Comment: I have change the wording in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Douma has touched on a central problem with your whole concept. The cross-product of two sets $A, B$ is the set $A \times B = \{(a,b)\;:\; a \in A, b \in B\}$. In particular, it is a set of ordered pairs. As such, your equation $\operatorname{pow}(S) = \operatorname{pow}(U) \times \operatorname{pow}(V)$ makes no sense. The elements in $\operatorname{pow}(S)$ are subsets of $S$, while the elements of $\operatorname{pow}(U) \times \operatorname{pow}(V)$ are ordered pairs of subsets of $S$. They cannot be the same.

In your original equation, it is fairly clear that by $a \times \operatorname{pow}(\{S\setminus a\})$, what you actually mean is $\{ \{a\} \cup V \;:\: V \in \operatorname{pow}(S \setminus \{a\})\}$. However, how this concept is supposed to generalize to arbitrary sets is not so clear.

---

What can be said here: Since $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $U \cup V = S$. If $A \subseteq S$, then $A_U := A \cap U \subseteq U$ and $A_V := A \cap V \subseteq V$. Conversely, if $B\subseteq U$ and $C\subseteq V$ are arbitrary, and if we set $A = B\cup C$, then $A_U = B$ and $A_V = C$. Thus we see that $$\operatorname{pow}(S) = \{ B \cup C \;:\; B \in \operatorname{pow}(U), C \in \operatorname{pow}(V)\}$$

Comment: Indeed. And as the decomposition of $A$ into $A_U$ and $A_V$ is unique, this defines a bijection between $\operatorname{pow(S)}$ and $\operatorname{pow(U)} \times \operatorname{pow(V)}$, which might have been the intended formulation.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, to prove that two sets are equal by showing that everything in set A is in set B and vice versa, pretty neat. As for the notation, it doesn't really bother me, I copied it from my number theory course note...and I know what it does, it behaves like **cross product**, only it does concatenation(although it would be nice if it has a name)